# Custom submit for Inline Entity forms

Tags: 7, forms, entities

I have a CCK called "Study" that has 2 inline entity referenced fields (Info, Log).
I want to create a node and set that node/entity to the 2nd entity ref field(Log); only when a checkbox option in 1st entity ref field(Info) is selected.

That is,
1st ERfield (Info) has a checkbox question with 3 options. If the user selects 3rd option, I have to create a node/entity and set that node as target id for 2nd ERfield (Log). How do I do this?

**My work so far**:

- in **custom validate handler**, I check if the 3rd checkbox is selected. If yes, then I call a custom submit handler (inside my custom validate)
- In the **custom submit**, I create entity for the 2nd ERfield and assign it to Study CCK 2nd ERfield. (please find code below for this)
- **problem facing**, entity is created and assigned, but after the form is completely submitted, the entity created is no longer referenced to 2nd ERfield. **HOW do I fix This?**

  ```
  /**
   * The custom validation function added to this form. 
   *  
   */
  function study_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    // check if 3rd checkbox is selected
    if (in_array('AddToLog', $array)) {
      $form_state['submit_handlers'][] = 'testsubmitfunc';
    }
  }

  function testsubmitfunc($form, &$form_state) {
    // create Log entity
    $lognode = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'log'));
    $lognode->uid = $form['uid']['#value'];
    $emw_lognode = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $lognode);
    $emw_lognode->save();
    $emw_lognode_nid = $emw_lognode->nid->value();

    // assign target id to the study entity
    $study_nid = $form_state['node']->nid;
    $study_e = entity_load('node', array($study_nid));
    $study_e[$study_nid]->field_erf_log = array('und'=>array('0'=>array('target_id' => $emw_lognode_nid)));
    entity_save('node', $study_e[$study_nid]);

    // exit();  // just to check if entity is created and assigned => is created and assigned, 
    // but removing exit(), and after the node is completely submitted,
    // 2nd ERfield(Log) is no longer assigned. (but the entity created is still there under admin->Content page)
  }
  ```